# Create a Webform Element as Checkbox

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to create a checkbox element for the webform in D8.
There is an example module, for creating and element, "webform_example_element" that actuly creates a text field element for the webform. Which works fine.

I just duplicated that module, to use it to create a checkbox element.

```
namespace Drupal\se_webform_element\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\FormElement;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class SEWebformElement extends FormElement {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return [
      '#input' => TRUE,
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      //'#size' => 60,

      '#process' => [
        [$class, 'processWebformElementExample'],
        [$class, 'processAjaxForm'],
      ],
      '#element_validate' => [
        [$class, 'validateSEWebformElement'],
      ],
      '#pre_render' => [
        [$class, 'preRenderSEWebformElement'],
      ],
      '#theme' => 'input__se_webform_element',
      '#theme_wrappers' => ['form_element'],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Processes a 'se_webform_element' element.
   */
  public static function processWebformElementExample(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    // Here you can add and manipulate your element's properties and callbacks.
    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * Webform element validation handler for #type 'se_webform_element'.
   */
  public static function validateSEWebformElement(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    // Here you can add custom validation logic.
  }

  /**
   * Prepares a #type 'email_multiple' render element for theme_element().
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   An associative array containing the properties of the element.
   *   Properties used: #title, #value, #description, #size, #maxlength,
   *   #placeholder, #required, #attributes.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The $element with prepared variables ready for theme_element().
   */
  public static function preRenderSEWebformElement(array $element) {

    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
    Element::setAttributes($element, ['id', 'name', 'options']);
    return $element;
  }

}
```

Which is not working as needed. 
It is saving the value, but when you edit the form, it does not reload it for the checkbox field. 
 What am I missing here?

Comment: Why can't you use either the Checkbox under Basic Elements or Checkboxes under Option Elements provided by the Webform module?

Comment: I need it to perform a specific action when this element is present in the form and checked.